# Counting values from two tables and returning the result in a single value

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

How to count value from two tables and return the result in a single value.?

I had two tables named order and affiliate, like below:

> order: 
>        order_ID(primary key), order_name, Order_status, affiliate_ID (foreign key)
>
> affiliate: 
>       affiliate_ID (primary key),affiliate_name

Now, I want to count the orders based on affiliate name by comparing the affiliate_ID on order table and affiliate table.

I have tried it like this:

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM order o  
AND (SELECT COUNT (affiliate_name) FROM affiliate a 
WHERE a.affiliate_id = O.affilate_id) AS total
```

It returns an error.

Comment: I'm a newbie to mysql.. can you help me to solve this..

Answer (score 2):

I feel this is what you need

```
SELECT a.affiliate_ID, a.affiliate_name, COUNT(o.order_ID) as total
FROM order o  
LEFT JOIN affiliate a ON o.affiliate_ID = a.affiliate_ID
GROUP BY o.affiliate_ID;
```

to add WHERE clause, see sample

```
SELECT a.affiliate_ID, a.affiliate_name, COUNT(o.order_ID) as total
FROM order o  
LEFT JOIN affiliate a ON o.affiliate_ID = a.affiliate_ID
WHERE o.affiliate_ID = 3
GROUP BY o.affiliate_ID;
```

Comment: your query works but wwhen i add AND and WHERE condition in your query returns error :(

Comment: Post a sample of when you add AND and WHERE so I can point out what you are doing wrong

Comment: SELECT a.affiliate_ID, a.firstname, COUNT(o.order_ID) as total FROM oc_order o LEFT JOIN oc_affiliate a ON o.affiliate_id = a.affiliate_id GROUP BY o.affiliate_id; AND DATE(date_added) = DATE('2018-04-17')

Comment: @AskBytes, you are adding the AND condition wrongly. Secondly, from which table are you supposed to pick the `date_added` because it's not specified on any of the table schema you provided.  @Kaddath, the WHERE clause can still be used when he needs to steamline the output

Comment: @OPMat yes, i got it..problem solved. thank you.. :)

Comment: @OPMat yeah i tagged the wrong person with an unclear comment, all signs that i need to leave SO for the day :P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but is this what you're looking for ?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as total
FROM order o  
JOIN affiliate a ON a.affiliate_id = o.affiliate_id
GROUP BY o.affiliate_id
```

Otherwise, provive sample & desired result example please.

Comment: i had tried your query it returns the error as "Unknown column 'o.affilate_id' in 'group statement' "

Comment: My bad, there was a typo (from your own query actually), I edited the query